# How to get audio button to appear in gridView using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html5-audio

Some of my audio button is working and some are not..

My `webForm1.aspx.cs` code:

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
        {
            byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((int)FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Length);
            string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(strConnString))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "insert into tblfiles5(Name, Data,FilePath) values (@Name, @Data,@FilePath)";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FilePath", "Files/" + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }
```

**EDIT**

After following @Andrew-Morton's advice to use HTML5 audio tag. This is my current result:

[Click here to view the  output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FI5X.png)

In the picture, the last two audio tags have a "Play" button which is not active.

[image]

Comment: The icon which appears is for a missing browser plug-in. Flash is being deprecated. It would be better to use HTML5 audio instead - you could start at [HTMLAudioElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) or search for a tutorial.

Comment: i am facing problem once again i.e when i upload a new file to the server the play button is not working..                                                                                                           '

Comment: **(1)** **Check again** that the file's URL is correct... **(2)** Maybe there is a limit of how many can be active at same time. Try same "not working" link with just one audio tag in your page (not 8 tags). **(3)** Share a link to an example of a not working `.wav` file for testing.

Comment: I got the answer i.e in above code i have to insert null value in filePath. Therefore insert into tblfiles5(Name, Data,FilePath) values (@Name, @Data,null) which is giving the output correctly and all new upload file is also have run button